# Avoid rollback when rails saves nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Model Overalltransaction

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :transactions

  Overalltransaction::Transaction.class_eval do
    attr_accessible :product_id, :rate, [...], :transaction_attributes
  end
```

*Update* Evaluation of nested attributes added to model

The create action controller for an overalltransaction,

```
@overalltransaction = Overalltransaction.new(params[:overalltransaction])
@transaction_count = params[:product_ids].count
@overalltransaction.transactions.build
@transactions = session[:product_ids].map do |product_id|
  transaction = Transaction.new
  transaction.rate =  @price
  [...]
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @overalltransaction.save
    @transactions.each do |transaction|
      transaction.save
    end
    [...]
  end
```

when comes commit time, terminal indicates:

```
(1.9ms)  BEGIN
(1.8ms)  ROLLBACK
```

for each product it should create.  What is missing/wrong here?  (rails 3.2.21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overalltransaction and Transaction being rather similar classes they also have similar validations.  The `ROLLBACK` was being initiated because one of the validations of the child record was not being met.

Answer (score 0):

You have to permit you nested attribute in Overalltransaction like

```
  params.require(:company).permit(:linkedin, :twitter, :facebook, :name, :organization_type, :industry, :phone, :year, :website, :user_id, :vision, :picture_attributes=> [:id, :image,:image_crop_x, :image_crop_y, :image_crop_w, :image_crop_h, :picturable_id, :picturable_type], :locations_attributes=>[:id, :street_address, :city, :suite, :state, :zip, :phone ,:country, :headquarter, :company_id, :_destroy])
```

as i have picture & location nested attribute.

Comment: I updated question with the block allowing access to the attributes. Behaviour however remains unchanged